# Qt console application with arguments during runtime

Tags: c++, qt, console, daemon

On my Debian machine i have a gui application as a websocket server. It works fine,  but now i need to run some more socket servers, and i don't think it would be a great picture of multiple gui apps on the screen.

According to this, applications are already re-made as a console app and successfully running in the background. But here comes  the problems: sometimes need to check logs, start/stop or add/remove something, etc.

How to do this with **already running** application? Like typing in terminal "app -start", "app --logs", etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your application listen to dbus messages. You can use the Qt D-Bus module for that:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html

You can then either send dbus messages from the command-line (with `dbus-send`), or you can write a GUI application that sends these messages.